# Meaning of "take"

Tags: meaning, word-meaning

> The trouble is there is a difference between what would be nice if it
>   were true and what is actually true. James could have pointed out that
>   while believing in Santa Claus works for young children, it doesn’t
>   work for everyone. If parents believed that Santa was going to deliver
>   presents on Christmas Eve then they wouldn’t go out and buy presents
>   for their children. **It would only take until Christmas morning to
>   realize that something wasn’t working with the belief ‘Santa Claus
>   exists’**.

-A little history of philosophy-

I don't know exactly the meaning of the word "**take**" in the sentence "**It would only take until Christmas morning to realize that something wasn’t working with the belief ‘Santa Claus exists’**"

I think the word "**take**" means "**need**".
I've tried to rewrite the sentence like this:
**It would just wait until Christmas morning  to realize that something wasn’t working with the belief ‘Santa Claus exists’**

Is this rewrite correct?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably familiar with *take* being used in phrases like "it will take five minutes" or "it takes a lot of energy."

Those sentences imply a sense of **need** as you mention, but I like to think of it also as **requiring/using/consuming** time/energy/effort/resources.

In your example sentence, it is the *realisation* that needs/requires/consumes **only [the time] until Christmas morning**.

So you might rewrite it as:

> The realisation ... only needed the time until Christmas morning.

Comment: Is "until" similar to "before"?

Comment: @XVI In a sense, yes. "Until" means the time leading up to something, though it can feel as though it means the time itself, e.g. "Do not do this until 3am."

Answer (score 1):

You definitely have the gist of the meaning, but I don't see where you've used "need" in your rewrite. Also, instead of "need", I would use "require." So the result would be:

> It would just **require** waiting until Christmas morning...